# python need help seeing where my set is being changed during iteration

Tags: python, set, minesweeper

I have built a minesweeper algorithm for a cs50 assignment. I have identidied issue with my code. (Inside the minesweeper class)

The program needs both minesweeper.py and runner.py and is executed with "python runner.py"

Upon running it with python runner.py it gives me a RuntimeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\seng\Downloads\minesweeper\minesweeper\runner.py", line 220, in <module>
    ai.add_knowledge(move, nearby)
  File "C:\Users\seng\Downloads\minesweeper\minesweeper\minesweeper.py", line 230, in add_knowledge
    self.updateknowledge()
  File "C:\Users\seng\Downloads\minesweeper\minesweeper\minesweeper.py", line 274, in updateknowledge
    for safe in safes:
RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

Here is the code.
minesweeper.py

```
import itertools
import random
import copy

class Minesweeper():
    """
    Minesweeper game representation
    """

    def __init__(self, height=8, width=8, mines=8):

        # Set initial width, height, and number of mines
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.mines = set()

        # Initialize an empty field with no mines
        self.board = []
        for i in range(self.height):
            row = []
            for j in range(self.width):
                row.append(False)
            self.board.append(row)

        # Add mines randomly
        while len(self.mines) != mines:
            i = random.randrange(height)
            j = random.randrange(width)
            if not self.board[i][j]:
                self.mines.add((i, j))
                self.board[i][j] = True

        # At first, player has found no mines
        self.mines_found = set()

    def print(self):
        """
        Prints a text-based representation
        of where mines are located.
        """
        for i in range(self.height):
            print("--" * self.width + "-")
            for j in range(self.width):
                if self.board[i][j]:
                    print("|X", end="")
                else:
                    print("| ", end="")
            print("|")
        print("--" * self.width + "-")

    def is_mine(self, cell):
        i, j = cell
        return self.board[i][j]

    def nearby_mines(self, cell):
        """
        Returns the number of mines that are
        within one row and column of a given cell,
        not including the cell itself.
        """

        # Keep count of nearby mines
        count = 0

        # Loop over all cells within one row and column
        for i in range(cell[0] - 1, cell[0] + 2):
            for j in range(cell[1] - 1, cell[1] + 2):

                # Ignore the cell itself
                if (i, j) == cell:
                    continue

                # Update count if cell in bounds and is mine
                if 0 <= i < self.height and 0 <= j < self.width:
                    if self.board[i][j]:
                        count += 1

        return count

    def won(self):
        """
        Checks if all mines have been flagged.
        """
        return self.mines_found == self.mines


class Sentence():
    """
    Logical statement about a Minesweeper game
    A sentence consists of a set of board cells,
    and a count of the number of those cells which are mines.
    """

    def __init__(self, cells, count):
        self.cells = set(cells)
        self.count = count

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.cells == other.cells and self.count == other.count

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.cells} = {self.count}"

    def known_mines(self):
        """
        Returns the set of all cells in self.cells known to be mines.
        """
        if len(self.cells) == self.count:
            return self.cells

    def known_safes(self):
        """
        Returns the set of all cells in self.cells known to be safe.
        """
        if 0 == self.count:
            return self.cells

    def mark_mine(self, cell):
        """
        Updates internal knowledge representation given the fact that
        a cell is known to be a mine.
        """
        if cell in self.cells:
            self.cells.remove(cell)
            self.count -= 1

    def mark_safe(self, cell):
        """
        Updates internal knowledge representation given the fact that
        a cell is known to be safe.
        """
        if cell in self.cells:
            self.cells.remove(cell)


class MinesweeperAI():
    """
    Minesweeper game player
    """

    def __init__(self, height=8, width=8):

        # Set initial height and width
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

        # Keep track of which cells have been clicked on
        self.moves_made = set()

        # Keep track of cells known to be safe or mines
        self.mines = set()
        self.safes = set()

        # List of sentences about the game known to be true
        self.knowledge = []

    def mark_mine(self, cell):
        """
        Marks a cell as a mine, and updates all knowledge
        to mark that cell as a mine as well.
        """
        self.mines.add(cell)
        for sentence in self.knowledge:
            sentence.mark_mine(cell)

    def mark_safe(self, cell):
        """
        Marks a cell as safe, and updates all knowledge
        to mark that cell as safe as well.
        """
        self.safes.add(cell)
        for sentence in self.knowledge:
            sentence.mark_safe(cell)

    def add_knowledge(self, cell, count):
        """
        Called when the Minesweeper board tells us, for a given
        safe cell, how many neighboring cells have mines in them.

        This function should:
            1) mark the cell as a move that has been made
            2) mark the cell as safe
            3) add a new sentence to the AI's knowledge base
               based on the value of `cell` and `count`
            4) mark any additional cells as safe or as mines
               if it can be concluded based on the AI's knowledge base
            5) add any new sentences to the AI's knowledge base
               if they can be inferred from existing knowledge
        """
        #1
        self.moves_made.add(cell)
        #2
        self.mark_safe(cell)
        #3
        i, j = cell
        removecell = []
        addcell = [(i-1, j-1), (i-1, j), (i-1, j+1), 
                (i, j-1), (i, j+1), 
                (i+1, j-1), (i+1, j), (i+1, j + 1),]
        for c in addcell:
            if c[0] < 0 or c[0] > 7 or c[1] < 0 or c[1] > 7:
                removecell.append(c)

        for c in removecell:
            addcell.remove(c)

        removecell = []
        for c in addcell:
            if c in self.mines:
                removecell.append(c)

        count -= len(removecell)
        for c in removecell:
            addcell.remove(c)

        removecell = []
        for c in addcell:
            if c in self.safes:
                removecell.append(c)

        for c in removecell:
            addcell.remove(c)

        #need filter for empty
        newsentence = Sentence(addcell, count)
        if len(newsentence.cells) > 0:
            self.knowledge.append(newsentence)
        print("dfs")

        self.updateknowledge()
        print("2")
        self.inference()
        print("3")


        

    def inference(self):
        for sentence1 in self.knowledge:
            for sentence2 in self.knowledge:
                if sentence1.cells.issubset(sentence2.cells):
                    new_cells = sentence2.cells - sentence1.cells
                    new_count = sentence2.count - sentence1.count
                    new_sentence = Sentence(new_cells, new_count)
                    if new_sentence not in self.knowledge:
                        self.knowledge.append(new_sentence)
                        self.updateknowledge()



    def updateknowledge(self):
        keepgoing = True
        while keepgoing:
            keepgoing = False
            for sentence in self.knowledge:

                mines = sentence.known_mines()
                if mines:
                    keepgoing = True
                    for mine in mines:
                        self.mark_mine(mine)

                safes = sentence.known_safes()
                if safes:
                    keepgoing = True
                    for safe in safes:
                        self.mark_safe(safe)


    def make_safe_move(self):
        """
        Returns a safe cell to choose on the Minesweeper board.
        The move must be known to be safe, and not already a move
        that has been made.

        This function may use the knowledge in self.mines, self.safes
        and self.moves_made, but should not modify any of those values.
        """
        for safe in self.safes:
            if safe not in self.moves_made:
                return safe

        return None

    def make_random_move(self):
        """
        Returns a move to make on the Minesweeper board.
        Should choose randomly among cells that:
            1) have not already been chosen, and
            2) are not known to be mines
        """
        moves = len(self.moves_made) + len(self.mines)
        if moves == 64:
            return None
        while True:
            i = random.randrange(self.height)
            j = random.randrange(self.height)
            if (i, j) not in self.moves_made and (i, j) not in self.mines:
                return (i, j)
```

runner.py

```
import pygame
import sys
import time

from minesweeper import Minesweeper, MinesweeperAI

HEIGHT = 8
WIDTH = 8
MINES = 8

# Colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GRAY = (180, 180, 180)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Create game
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 600, 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Fonts
OPEN_SANS = "assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf"
smallFont = pygame.font.Font(OPEN_SANS, 20)
mediumFont = pygame.font.Font(OPEN_SANS, 28)
largeFont = pygame.font.Font(OPEN_SANS, 40)

# Compute board size
BOARD_PADDING = 20
board_width = ((2 / 3) * width) - (BOARD_PADDING * 2)
board_height = height - (BOARD_PADDING * 2)
cell_size = int(min(board_width / WIDTH, board_height / HEIGHT))
board_origin = (BOARD_PADDING, BOARD_PADDING)

# Add images
flag = pygame.image.load("assets/images/flag.png")
flag = pygame.transform.scale(flag, (cell_size, cell_size))
mine = pygame.image.load("assets/images/mine.png")
mine = pygame.transform.scale(mine, (cell_size, cell_size))

# Create game and AI agent
game = Minesweeper(height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH, mines=MINES)
ai = MinesweeperAI(height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)

# Keep track of revealed cells, flagged cells, and if a mine was hit
revealed = set()
flags = set()
lost = False

# Show instructions initially
instructions = True

while True:

    # Check if game quit
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Show game instructions
    if instructions:

        # Title
        title = largeFont.render("Play Minesweeper", True, WHITE)
        titleRect = title.get_rect()
        titleRect.center = ((width / 2), 50)
        screen.blit(title, titleRect)

        # Rules
        rules = [
            "Click a cell to reveal it.",
            "Right-click a cell to mark it as a mine.",
            "Mark all mines successfully to win!"
        ]
        for i, rule in enumerate(rules):
            line = smallFont.render(rule, True, WHITE)
            lineRect = line.get_rect()
            lineRect.center = ((width / 2), 150 + 30 * i)
            screen.blit(line, lineRect)

        # Play game button
        buttonRect = pygame.Rect((width / 4), (3 / 4) * height, width / 2, 50)
        buttonText = mediumFont.render("Play Game", True, BLACK)
        buttonTextRect = buttonText.get_rect()
        buttonTextRect.center = buttonRect.center
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, buttonRect)
        screen.blit(buttonText, buttonTextRect)

        # Check if play button clicked
        click, _, _ = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if click == 1:
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if buttonRect.collidepoint(mouse):
                instructions = False
                time.sleep(0.3)

        pygame.display.flip()
        continue

    # Draw board
    cells = []
    for i in range(HEIGHT):
        row = []
        for j in range(WIDTH):

            # Draw rectangle for cell
            rect = pygame.Rect(
                board_origin[0] + j * cell_size,
                board_origin[1] + i * cell_size,
                cell_size, cell_size
            )
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, rect, 3)

            # Add a mine, flag, or number if needed
            if game.is_mine((i, j)) and lost:
                screen.blit(mine, rect)
            elif (i, j) in flags:
                screen.blit(flag, rect)
            elif (i, j) in revealed:
                neighbors = smallFont.render(
                    str(game.nearby_mines((i, j))),
                    True, BLACK
                )
                neighborsTextRect = neighbors.get_rect()
                neighborsTextRect.center = rect.center
                screen.blit(neighbors, neighborsTextRect)

            row.append(rect)
        cells.append(row)

    # AI Move button
    aiButton = pygame.Rect(
        (2 / 3) * width + BOARD_PADDING, (1 / 3) * height - 50,
        (width / 3) - BOARD_PADDING * 2, 50
    )
    buttonText = mediumFont.render("AI Move", True, BLACK)
    buttonRect = buttonText.get_rect()
    buttonRect.center = aiButton.center
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, aiButton)
    screen.blit(buttonText, buttonRect)

    # Reset button
    resetButton = pygame.Rect(
        (2 / 3) * width + BOARD_PADDING, (1 / 3) * height + 20,
        (width / 3) - BOARD_PADDING * 2, 50
    )
    buttonText = mediumFont.render("Reset", True, BLACK)
    buttonRect = buttonText.get_rect()
    buttonRect.center = resetButton.center
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, resetButton)
    screen.blit(buttonText, buttonRect)

    # Display text
    text = "Lost" if lost else "Won" if game.mines == flags else ""
    text = mediumFont.render(text, True, WHITE)
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = ((5 / 6) * width, (2 / 3) * height)
    screen.blit(text, textRect)

    move = None

    left, _, right = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    # Check for a right-click to toggle flagging
    if right == 1 and not lost:
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for i in range(HEIGHT):
            for j in range(WIDTH):
                if cells[i][j].collidepoint(mouse) and (i, j) not in revealed:
                    if (i, j) in flags:
                        flags.remove((i, j))
                    else:
                        flags.add((i, j))
                    time.sleep(0.2)

    elif left == 1:
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # If AI button clicked, make an AI move
        if aiButton.collidepoint(mouse) and not lost:
            move = ai.make_safe_move()
            if move is None:
                move = ai.make_random_move()
                if move is None:
                    flags = ai.mines.copy()
                    print("No moves left to make.")
                else:
                    print("No known safe moves, AI making random move.")
            else:
                print("AI making safe move.")
            time.sleep(0.2)

        # Reset game state
        elif resetButton.collidepoint(mouse):
            game = Minesweeper(height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH, mines=MINES)
            ai = MinesweeperAI(height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
            revealed = set()
            flags = set()
            lost = False
            continue

        # User-made move
        elif not lost:
            for i in range(HEIGHT):
                for j in range(WIDTH):
                    if (cells[i][j].collidepoint(mouse)
                            and (i, j) not in flags
                            and (i, j) not in revealed):
                        move = (i, j)

    # Make move and update AI knowledge
    if move:
        if game.is_mine(move):
            lost = True
        else:
            nearby = game.nearby_mines(move)
            revealed.add(move)
            ai.add_knowledge(move, nearby)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

I understand that this is where the error occurs, and replacing my iterated object with a copy fixes the issue. Problem is i fail to see where i am editing the set in the first place.

```
class MinesweeperAI:
    def updateknowledge(self):
        ...
        safes = sentence.known_safes()
        if safes:
            keepgoing = True
            for safe in safes.copy():
                self.mark_safe(safe)
```

`self.mark_safe(safe)` leads to (in minesweeper class)

```
self.safes.add(cell)
        for sentence in self.knowledge:
            sentence.mark_safe(cell)
```

and `sentence.mark_safe(cell)` leads to

```
if cell in self.cells:
            self.cells.remove(cell)
```

So how is this affecting the set of `safes` which I am iterating over? Would appreciate advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code is "marking safes" while looping over "safes".

Try changing:

```
for safe in self.safes:
```

to:

```
for safe in list(self.safes):
```

That will make a copy of the "safes" to loop over, leaving the underlying set available for updates.

Comment: In your code `self.cells.remove(cell)` is modifying the set. You can't do that while iterating over `self.cells`. That's why you need a copy to iterate over while you remove from `self.cells`